# content-security-policy allows ginger extension to load content

Tags: php, content-security-policy

when I install this ginger extension on chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-and-grammar-checker/kdfieneakcjfaiglcfcgkidlkmlijjnh?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

and I view my page:
http://start.funmoods.com/results.php?q=hotel.com&a=undefined&category=web&start=1&fc=br

as you can see in the top when "ginger" extension is on, the page is lowered.

do you know why does my csp allowed ginger to load its html?

here are my csp headers:

you can view them by yourself in chrome developer box

Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Security-Policy:default-src *; script-src 'self' http://www.google-analytics.com http://suggest.infospace.com http://api.autocompleteplus.com http://www.googletagservices.com  http://d.yimg.com https://completr.appspot.com; frame-src 'self'  http://*.yhs4.search.yahoo.com  http://ad.adserver-pro.net; font-src 'none' ; connect-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' ;
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 06 Nov 2013 09:22:47 GMT
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:fm=YT11bmRlZmluZWQmdXJlZj0mY2Q9JmNyPSY%3D; expires=Fri, 06-Dec-2013 09:22:47 GMT
Set-Cookie:rs=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%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 27-Oct-2015 09:22:47 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Security-Policy:default-src *; script-src 'self' http://www.google-analytics.com http://suggest.infospace.com http://api.autocompleteplus.com http://www.googletagservices.com  http://d.yimg.com https://completr.appspot.com; frame-src 'self'  http://*.yhs4.search.yahoo.com  http://ad.adserver-pro.net; font-src 'none' ; connect-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' ;
X-WebKit-CSP:default-src *; script-src 'self' http://www.google-analytics.com http://suggest.infospace.com http://api.autocompleteplus.com http://www.googletagservices.com  http://d.yimg.com https://completr.appspot.com; frame-src 'self'  http://*.yhs4.search.yahoo.com  http://ad.adserver-pro.net; font-src 'none' ; connect-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: Because that's not what the CSP does.

> According to the CSP Processing Model, CSP should not interfere with the operation of browser add-ons or extensions installed by the user. This feature of CSP effectively allows any add-on or extension to inject script into web sites, regardless of the origin of that script, and thus be exempt to CSP policies. The W3C Web Application Security Working Group considers such script to be part of the Trusted Computing Base implemented by the browser; however, some consider this exemption to be a potential security hole that could be exploited by malicious or compromised add-ons or extensions.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy

Comment: Is there a way to disable the extension scripts?

Comment: Extensions are part of the browser, it doesn't really matter whether they're built-in or installed by the user additionally. No, you cannot disable any part of the browser with your website.